# How to group for the following table in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table which have 3 fields like 
field1, field2 and field3

fiel1 is primary key

table structure:

```
create table testtable (
    field1 serial PRIMARY KEY,
    field2 varchar(200),
    field3 varchar(200)
);
```

Insert Data:

```
insert into testtable (field2,field3) VALUES 
('f1','item1'),
('f2','item2'),
('f3','item3'),
('f4','item1'),
('f1','item2'),
('f2','item3'),
('f5','item5'),
('f2','item4'),
('f1','item5');
```

It now looks like this:

```
select * from testtable;
 feild1 | field2 | field3 
--------+--------+--------
      1 | f1     | item1
      2 | f2     | item2
      3 | f3     | item3
      4 | f4     | item1
      5 | f1     | item2
      6 | f2     | item3
      7 | f5     | item5
      8 | f2     | item4
      9 | f1     | item5
```

As you can see field2 and field3 are repeating themselves.
I want to group by field2, but the problem is I cannot access field3.

If I do `GROUP BY field2`, then I cannot access all the values present in field3.

I can't do `select * from testtable where field2="f1"`
because I cannot check and execute so many queries for all the values present in field2, that would executing lot of queries, and I need a better solution, so that 1 query or 2 or subquery can do it.
Assume that data is in millions.

Comment: What kind of result do you want the query to return?

Comment: I want to group by field2 and access field3 using field2, i.e. if I have 'f1', then it should return me item1, item2 and item5 according to above data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select field2, array_agg(field3)
from testtable
group by 1
order by 1;

 field2 |      array_agg      
--------+---------------------
 f1     | {item5,item2,item1}
 f2     | {item4,item3,item2}
 f3     | {item3}
 f4     | {item1}
 f5     | {item5}
(5 rows)
```

or

```
select field2, string_agg(field3, ' | ')
from testtable
group by 1
order by 1;

 field2 |      string_agg       
--------+-----------------------
 f1     | item5 | item2 | item1
 f2     | item4 | item3 | item2
 f3     | item3
 f4     | item1
 f5     | item5
(5 rows)
```